# Como receber somente letras e espaços no input?

Tags: python

```
def registro(name="", idade=0, local=""):
    while name.isalpha() == False:
            name = input("Digite seu nome: ")
            if name.isalpha():
                name.isalpha() == True
            else:
                print("Por favor digite um nome válido.(Não deve conter espaços)")
```

Neste código eu usei o "isalpha()" pelo motivo de receber somente letras, porém, isto não me permite colocar espaços, qual substituição de código eu poderia fazer para o Input receber somente as letras e espaços?

Comment: O uso do isalpha foi para não receber números ou caracteres especiais no nome, eu não estava ciente que o isalpha anulava os espaços. Quanto ao problema do True eu notei isso também e ja arrumei essa parte do código, mas no caso, como eu faria esse input receber somente letras e espaços?

Comment: Creio que agora tenha ficado mais claro.

Answer (score 2):

Como `isalpha()` retorna `True` apenas se todos os caracteres forem letras, e o nome pode ter letras e espaços, então o jeito é verificar os caracteres um a um. Assim:

```
while True:
    name = input("Digite seu nome: ")
    if all(c.isalpha() or c.isspace() for c in name):
        break # sai do while
    else:
        print("Por favor digite um nome válido (somente letras e espaços)")
```

Eu uso `all`, que retorna `True` se todos os caracteres da strings satisfizerem a condição (que no caso é `c.isalpha() or c.isspace()`, ou seja, "é uma letra ou um espaço".

Se todos os caracteres estiverem nessa condição, o `break` interrompe o loop. Caso contrário, a mensagem de erro é impressa e pede-se que digite novamente.

---

Só lembrando que `isalpha` é bem abrangente e considera também letras de outros alfabetos (japonês, russo, árabe, etc), e `isspace` também considera quebras de linha, TAB, entre outros.

Se quiser ser mais restrito, basta criar uma string contendo somente os caracteres válidos e usá-la no teste:

```
from string import ascii_letters
 
# acrescentei o espaço e algumas letras acentuadas, adicione tudo que precisar aqui 
validos = ascii_letters + ' áéíóú'
while True:
    name = input("Digite seu nome: ")
    if all(c in validos for c in name):
        break # sai do while
    else:
        print("Por favor digite um nome válido (somente letras e espaços)")
```

No exemplo acima usei as letras ASCII (todas as letras de "a" a "z", maiúsculas e minúsculas), e adicionei o espaço e algumas letras acentuadas. Então basta acrescentar todos os caracteres que precisar ali.